# How can I remove a dynamically generated class with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a dynamically generated html grid with the following javascript code and html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/colorwalk.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div id="colorgrid"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="colorbuttons">
        <button class="buttonsize white">
        <button class="buttonsize red">
        <button class="buttonsize green">
        <button class="buttonsize orange">
        <button class="buttonsize pink">
        <button class="buttonsize purple">
    </div>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    const colors = Array.of('red', 'green', 'orange', 'pink', 'purple');
    let y = 0;
    let x = 0
    for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < 30; j++) {
            const randomColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
            $block = $('<div></div>').addClass('blockattribute').addClass(randomColor).css({ left: x, top:y });
            $block.appendTo('#colorgrid');
            x >= 580 ? x = 0 : x = x + 20
            $('.blockattribute').first().addClass('gray');
        }
        y = y + 20;
    }
});
```

The problem that I am encountering is line 11 in the JS snippet (`$('.blockattribute').first().addClass('gray');`). I want the very first block on the grid to have a class of `.gray`. The class makes the background color gray but when I inspect the element in the console I see that my block looks like this:

`<div class="blockattribute red gray" style="left: 0px; top: 0px;"></div>`

My problem is that I need to remove the `red` class but because it is dynamically created, I am unable to select it before hand. Is there a way I can see a list of jQuery classes and then select the right one?

Comment: Have you tried: `$('.blockattribute').first().addClass('gray').removeClass('red');`?

Comment: But how would you know it's red before the page renders? It could be red, pink, orange, green, or purple.

Comment: Why not use `$('.blockattribute').first().removeClass('red');` after the page rendered?

Comment: You can remove all classes and add back `$('.blockattribute').removeClass().addClass('blockattribute gray')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove all other color classes before adding `gray` like follwing

```
$('.blockattribute').first().removeClass(colors.join(' ')).addClass('gray');
```